# azure mobile service add parameter toast winRT

Tags: mobile, azure, service, push

I use Azure Mobile Services notification in my app.
If my app is already launched, I have to get the id of the new product (by the notification) and do some treatments.

I followed this tutorial : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709907.aspx

The problem is : how get id of this new product by accessing notificationContent ?

I try some things :

Azure side, on JS :

```
                push.wns.sendToastText04(channel.currentkey, {
                      text1: "New product added : " + item.name,
                      param1: item.id});
```

or

```
                push.wns.sendToastText04(channel.currentkey, {
                      text1: "New product added : " + item.name,
                      param: item.id});
```

or

```
                push.wns.sendToastText04(channel.currentkey, {
                      text1: "New product added : " + item.name,
                      launch: item.id});
```

but can't get the id in notificationContent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer :

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/828e84fc-8441-4aa4-b33e-4f73bdcf1488/opening-a-page-when-user-clicks-on-a-toast-notification

Hope it can help people later !